# Run K - means Algorithm

Tags: arrays, boolean, cluster-analysis, index-error

New in python learning clustering...
Getting this error, I see index error but not sure how to fix..
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I don't know. Tried changing dataframe to boolean array

`kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)  kmeans.fit(df_sub) df_sub['clusters'] = kmeans.fit_predict(df_sub)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.